# Is it possible to link someone to update iOS version from inside an app?

Tags: ios

I'd like to be able to link users to update to the latest iOS version (Not the app version - the OS version).

Is this possible to do programmatically from inside an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by

1- Store current new IOS version number in server (to pull it)

2- Compare version of system that you read from the app with step1

3- Show pop up to tell user to update his IOS version

4- Navigate to settings page with (show update path in popup Settings->General....>)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It opens the settings for the app. I'm trying to open the device settings so I can update the OS.

Comment: From what I understand this used to be possible with the following url:
App-Prefs:root=General&path=Software%20Update

It looks like this has been deprecated in iOS 11+

Comment: this the only legal & available way starting from ios 11 , you can't open update page directly from your app